# How to loop multiple dependent task in Ansible

Tags: ansible, nested-loops

I am trying to have 2 tasks using the same variables but with the second task beind dependent on the result of the first task. If I use register to note the result of the first task I end up creating a list which the second task cannot use effectively since it creates a many to many loop relation ship when I simply want the item to run in both task first, then the second item to run in both tasks, then the 3rd etc..

For example, search if directory exists, and if it exists then change its permissions. I have a list of directories to loop through to check if they exist and then change those permissions. How do I loop it in Ansible to that it only goes by each of them in the list in each task? Below is my last attempt.

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    folders_to_change:
      - /Users/Documents/test_folder1
      - /Users/Documents/test_folder2
  tasks:
  - name: Ansible check file exists example.
    stat:
      path: "{{ item }}"
    register: file_details
    loop:
      "{{ folders_to_change }}"

  - name: Change permissions of folder
      file:
        path: "{{ folders_to_change[{{ item }}] }}"
        owner: root
        group: root
        mode: 777
        state: directory
    when: file_details.stat.exists.isdir["{{ item }}"]
    loop:
      "{{ range(0 - folders_to_change|len }}"
```

Comment: i am having trouble understanding the `file` task you have come up with. is your goal to find if the 2 folders in `folders_to_change` exist, and if yes, run the `file` task on them?

Comment: yes that is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, but you have a few things misplaced.

The `["{{ item }}"]` located at the wrong end of the expression, since the `isdir` is just an attribute, and not a list, but `file_details.results` is a `list`

```yaml
    when: file_details.results[item].stat.isdir
```

There's also no need to involve the jinja2 mustaches since a `when:` is already a jinja2 expression, and *for sure* no need to quote an int as `range` emits.

Which brings us to the next item: [`range`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#range) wants two arguments, but you specified an expression `0 - len`, which is going to range over a negative number. The starting 0 is implied, so really just omit it:

```yaml
    when: file_details.results[item].stat.isdir
    loop:
      "{{ range(folders_to_change|length) }}"
```

Finally, if you prefer that style of constantly using `range` and reaching back to the global variable easier, more power to you, but the `results` list keeps track of the original `item` key in its `dict` entries, thus:

```yaml
  - name: Change permissions of folder
    file:
        path: "{{ item.item }}"
        owner: root
        group: root
        mode: 777
        state: directory
    when: item.stat.isdir
    loop: "{{ file_details.results }}"
```

You really will benefit from some use of `debug: var=file_details` (or whatever) going forward to look at the shape of the data available to you

Comment: quick correction-> when: item.stat.exists.isdir is failing as it boolean and doesn't have the isdir attribute. removing that and it works. In the interest of making the code as reusable as possible- how would I add the owner and group as part of a sub list of files i.e ["/Users/Documents/test_folder1","root","root"] that way I can have different file permission for each file. I tried using 'item.item.1' and 'item.item.2'  but that only gave me '/' and 'U'.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that -- too much copy-pasta from the original question, not enough thinking :-) as for your follow-on question, it would be `vars: { folders_to_change: [ { path: /Users/Documents/test_folder1, user: root, group: root } ] }` type deal, and then update the attribute references accordingly